Invalid Grant Error with MSAL in Next.js - Insufficient Permissions (AADB2C90205)
I am implementing login functionality in my Next.js application using Azure AD B2C and the MSAL library. However, I am encountering the following error when attempting to log in:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADB2C90205:This application does not have sufficient permissions 
    against this web resource to perform the operation.
    \r\nCorrelation ID: 425d0c39-3bf7-48be-9b81-8bc5cd5abc02\r\nTimestamp: 2024-09-06 12:41:31Z\r\n"
}

Here are the relevant details:
@azure/msal-browser: ^3.23.0
@azure/msal-react: ^2.0.13

I am using Azure AD B2C to handle user authentication.
Steps Taken:
I registered the application in Azure AD B2C.
Configured the necessary redirect URIs and API permissions.
Set up the MSAL configuration in my Next.js app using the MSAL React library.
Troubleshooting Attempts:
Checked API permissions and made sure they were granted admin consent.
Verified that the redirect URIs and scopes in my MSAL configuration match those in Azure AD B2C.
Question: What might be causing this "insufficient permissions" error, and how can I resolve it? Is there something specific I need to configure in Azure AD B2C for MSAL to successfully authenticate users?
Any help would be appreciated!

Can you share your API permission details here.

Is this the API permissions you are using?

I tried a sample next.js project and successfully Logged in and Logged out using the scope as openid and offline_access. My page looks like this.

The error you are facing occurs if you haven't granted admin consent in the API permissions. I used the permissions in the above comment. May I know the scope you are using in your next.js project?


{ "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "AADB2C90205: This application does not have sufficient permissions against this web resource to perform the operation.\r\nCorrelation ID: 425d0c39-3bf7-48be-9b81-8bc5cd5abc02\r\nTimestamp: 2024-09-06 12:41:31Z\r\n" }

The error you are facing occurs if you haven't granted admin consent for the API permissions.
I used the scopes openid and offline_access for user authentication and granted admin consent, as shown in the API permissions below.

I tried the sample Next.js application below using Azure AD B2C to handle user authentication.
pages/_app.js :
import { MsalProvider } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { PublicClientApplication } from "@azure/msal-browser";
import { msalConfig } from "../msalConfig";
import "../styles/globals.css";
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MsalProvider>
  );
}
export default MyApp;

pages/index.js :
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { loginRequest } from "../msalConfig";
import { useEffect } from "react";
export default function Home() {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      console.log("Logged in user:", accounts[0]);
    }
  }, [accounts]);
  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginPopup(loginRequest).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };
  const handleLogout = () => {
    instance.logoutPopup().catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to Azure AD B2C</h1>
      {accounts.length > 0 ? (
        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

pages/profile.js :
import { useMsal } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function Profile() {
  const { accounts } = useMsal();
  const [ setUserProfile] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      const account = accounts[0];
      setUserProfile(account);
    }
  }, [accounts]);
}

msalConfig.js :
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: "<client_ID>",  
      authority: "https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<policyName>",  
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000",  
      knownAuthorities: ["<tenantName>.b2clogin.com"],  
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: "localStorage",  
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, 
    },
  };
  export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", "offline_access"],  
  };

package.json :
{
  "name": "msal-nextjs-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.23.0",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^2.0.13",
    "next": "14.2.9",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  }
}

I added the URL below under Authentication redirect URI as a Single-page application, as shown.
http://localhost:3000


Output :
I successfully logged into Azure AD B2C by clicking the Login button, as shown below.

After logging in, I got the below page.

